# Tracking 5.1.1 User Unknown in Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010, ndr

We recently discovered that one of our mailboxes was missing an important email alias, because the person that did our marketing forgot to ask for it to be created.

Is there any way in Exchange that we can track any emails that may have been sent to an un-known alias? They all received a `550 5.1.1 User Unknown` NDR.

I don't expect to know what the content of the email is, but even just the number of requests would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best method for tracking that down would be the transport/message tracking logs on the hub servers.

But, they automatically rotate (I believe the default is 30 days) - do yours go back far enough to cover the timeframe that you're interested in?

Comment: Probably not, but I'll take a look. It was printed on brochures that have been handed out over the last 12 months.

Comment: Hmm this only seems to show messages that Exchange accepted, or originated from Exchange. I can see the test messages we sent internally this morning, but not the test messages we sent externally. Might not be possible...

Comment: @MarkHenderson Hmm.  I thought it stored those kinds of rejections in there.. are your hubs the ones sending the NDR response to the external addresses?  Or are there edge servers that're doing it instead?

Comment: It's a pretty small single-server setup, so there's only one exchange server that does everything. I'm about to head home now but I will take another look tomorrow.